# Why are my contributions not being shown in the heat map?

Tags: github

I have been uploading files the same way for the past month. But today suddenly they are not showing up on my profile. Any idea why?

Here you can see the commits in detail on May 22nd:
[image]

Here you can see the heat map, it says no commits on May 22nd:
[image]

Here is my GitHub link : https://github.com/Vijay1126

Comment: Did you follow [the link](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile) just under the graph?

Comment: Yes I did, still no luck @jonrsharpe

Comment: Really?! Even if *nothing* else applies, https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#commit-was-made-less-than-24-hours-ago surely does...

Comment: Looks like it's not just me, haha
Link: https://downdetector.com/status/github/  @jonrsharpe

Comment: See also https://www.githubstatus.com/. But even if the site was running fine, the above would apply.